# Powershell arrays into html tables

Tags: arrays, powershell, html-table

Ok so I have my first ever powershell script and it works exactly how I want it to. The output was just to a txt file and it was bland.

Totally reworked it to give all results into a single array.

mind you there maybe a better way to do this or I may have put too much code so suggestions welcomed....

my end goal is a html with just 2 rows.... Item and Result

this is ran on a machine that will get registry settings, services startup types and local acct status.

I just cant figure out how to do a table and cycle through the arrays.

thanks for your help as it is greatly apprecaited!!!!

```
# Static array of registry keys
$RegKeys = @("DisableNotificationCenter","AutoConfiURL","HibernateEnabled","HideSCAHealth","NoDriveTypeAutoRun","TurnOffSidebar","EnableBaloonTips","UseDomainNameDevolution","DomainNameDevolutionlevel","*.one.ads","*","SearchOrderConfig","NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers","DisabledComponents","fAllowToGetHelp","fDenyTSConnections","EnableLUA","dontdisplaylastusername")
#Static array of service names
$Services = @("LanmanServer","MPSSVC","WinDefend","WSCSVC","TRKWKS","NAPAGENT","WUAUSERV")
#Static array of users 
$Users = @("Admin","Guest")

#Registry Keys
$dnc = 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer'
if (Test-Path $dnc) {$dnc = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer").DisableNotificationCenter}
else {$dnc = "Key not Found"}
$acu = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'
if (Test-Path $acu) {$acu = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings").AutoConfigURL}
else {$acu = "Key not Found"}
$he = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power'
if (Test-Path $he) {$he = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power").HibernateEnabled}
else {$he = "Key not Found"}
$hscah = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer'
if (Test-Path $hscah) {$hscah = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer").HideSCAHealth}
else {$hscah = "Key not Found"}
$ndtar = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer'
if (Test-Path $ndtar) {$ndtar = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer").NoDriveTypeAutoRun}
else {$ndtar = "Key not Found"}
$tos = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\Windows\Sidebar'
if (Test-Path $tos) {$tos = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\Windows\Sidebar").TurnOffSidebar}
else {$tos = "Key not Found"}
$ebt = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Advanced'
if (Test-Path $ebt) {$ebt = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Advanced").EnableBaloonTips}
else {$ebt = "Key not Found"}
$udnd = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient'
if (Test-Path $udnd) {$udnd = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient").UseDomainNameDevolution}
else {$udnd = "Key not Found"}
$dndl = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CURRENTCONTROLSET\SERVICES\Dnscache\Parameters'
if (Test-Path $dndl) {$dndl = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CURRENTCONTROLSET\SERVICES\Dnscache\Parameters").DomainNameDevolutionlevel}
else {$dndl = "Key not Found"}
$oads = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\bms.com\*.one.ads'
if (Test-Path $oads) {$oads = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\bms.com\*.one.ads")."*"}
else {$oads = "Key not Found"}
$ads = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\bms.com\*.one.ads'
if (Test-Path $ads) {$ads = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\bms.com\")."*"}
else {$ads = "Key not Found"}
$soc = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching'
if (Test-Path $soc) {$soc = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching").SearchOrderConfig}
else {$soc = "Key not Found"}
$narwlou = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU'
if (Test-Path $narwlou) {$narwlou = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU").NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers}
else {$narwlou = "Key not Found"}
$dc = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters'
if (Test-Path $dc) {$dc = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters").DisabledComponents}
else {$dc = "Key not Found"}
$atgh = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance'
if (Test-Path $atgh) {$atgh = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance").fAllowToGetHelp}
else {$atgh = "Key not Found"}
$dtsc = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services'
if (Test-Path $dtsc) {$dtsc = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services").fDenyTSConnections}
else {$dtsc = "Key not Found"}
$elua = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\System'
if (Test-Path $elua) {$elua = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\System").EnableLUA}
else {$elua = "Key not Found"}
$ddlun = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\System'
if (Test-Path $ddlun) {$ddlun = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\Policies\System").dontdisplaylastusername}
else {$ddlun = "Key not Found"}

#Services
$ls = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "Name='LanmanServer'").StartMode 
$mpssvc = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "Name='MPSSVC'").StartMode 
$wd = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "Name='WinDefend'").StartMode 
$wscsvc = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "Name='WSCSVC'").StartMode 
$trkwks = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "Name='TRKWKS'").StartMode 
$napagent = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "Name='NAPAGENT'").StartMode 
$wuauserv = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "Name='WUAUSERV'").StartMode 

#Local Accounts
$Adm = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True' AND Name='Administrator'"
$Admin = $Adm.Disabled
$Gu = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True' AND Name='Guest'"
$Guest = $Gu.Disabled

#Make individual arrays from each queried information
$RegValues = @($dnc,$acu,$he,$hscah,$ndtar,$tos,$ebt,$udnd,$dndl,$oads,$ads,$soc,$narwlou,$dc,$atgh,$dtsc,$elua,$ddlun)
$ServiceValues = @($ls,$mpssvc,$wd,$wscsvc,$trkwks,$napagent,$wuauserv)
$UsersValues = @($Admin,$Guest)

#Make array of all keys
$RegAll = @($RegKeys[0], $RegValues[0],$RegKeys[1], $RegValues[1],$RegKeys[2], $RegValues[2],$RegKeys[3], $RegValues[3], $RegKeys[4], $RegValues[4], $RegKeys[5], $RegValues[5]
$RegKeys[6], $RegValues[6], $RegKeys[7], $RegValues[7], $RegKeys[8], $RegValues[8], $RegKeys[9], $RegValues[9], $RegKeys[10], $RegValues[10]
$RegKeys[11], $RegValues[11], $RegKeys[12], $RegValues[12], $RegKeys[13], $RegValues[13], $RegKeys[14], $RegValues[14], $RegKeys[15], $RegValues[15]
$RegKeys[16], $RegValues[16], $RegKeys[17], $RegValues[17], $RegKeys[18], $RegValues[18], $Services[0], $ServiceValues[0], $Services[1], $ServiceValues[1]
, $Services[2], $ServiceValues[2], $Services[3], $ServiceValues[3], $Services[4], $ServiceValues[4], $Services[5], $ServiceValues[5], $Services[6], $ServiceValues[6],
$Users[0], $UsersValues[0], $Users[1], $UsersValues[1])

#output to html
$RegAll # | Select @{label='Item';expression={$_}} | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment -Property 'Item' |Out-File c:\Scripts.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example which I have used in a script. You can adpt it on your script. Ask when you need help.

```
    $YourArray = @()

#Object one for the array
 $test1 = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
    $test1 | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Propert_1 –Value "Example1"
    $test1 | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Propert_2 –Value "Example2"
    $test1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Propert_3 -Value "Example3"

#Object two for the array
 $test2 = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
    $test2 | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Propert_1 –Value "Example_2_1"
    $test2 | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Propert_2 –Value "Example_2_2"
    $test2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Propert_3 -Value "Example_2_3"

$YourArray = $test1,$test2

$beginning = { 
#html code the format of the table
 @'
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
        BODY{background-color:#b0c4de;}
        TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;} 
        TH{font-family:SegoeUI, sans-serif; font-size:15; border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#778899}
        TD{font-family:Consolas, sans-serif; font-size:12; border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
        tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#d3d3d3;} 
        tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:white;} 

    </STYLE>

    </head>
    <h1>Stackoverflow example</h1>
    <table>
    <tr><th>Propert_1</th><th>Propert_2</th><th>Propert_3</th></tr>
'@
}
#Mapping between Property and table
    $process = {
        $Propert_1 = $_.Propert_1
        $Propert_2 = $_.Propert_2
        $Propert_3 = $_.Propert_3



        '<tr>'
        '<td bgcolor="#33CC33">{0}</td>' -f $Propert_1
        '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">{0}</td>' -f $Propert_2
        '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">{0}</td>' -f $Propert_3
        '</tr>'

    }


    $end = { 
 @'
        </table>
        </html>
        </body>
'@


    }

#Export the array in a html sheet
$YourArray |   ForEach-Object -Begin $beginning -Process $process -End $end |  Out-File -FilePath "U:\Export_Report.html" -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: ok i removed the following:

#Mapping between Property and table
    $process = {
        $Propert_1 = $_.Propert_1
        $Propert_2 = $_.Propert_2

removed ==>         $Propert_3 = $_.Propert_3

removed ==>         '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">{0}</td>' -f $Propert_3

changed array name and html file name...

changed first row to FFFFFF as well... so now i have an empty 2 row...

I am not sure how to get the array to rip through and fill out the table...

Comment: Side note I took my array and only kept the first 2 and the report html dropped to 2 rows.. so it seems it is going there..for each row but just not populating the data.... im stumped..hah

Comment: How does your array look like exactly?

Comment: Changed the title and centered it...
I have 2 columns ( Item | Result ) with black txt and grey background
Then I have white rows under it with no txt.

what was interesting was I took my array and removed ALL but 
$RegAll = $RegKeys[0], $RegValues[0]

and then i had 2 rows so still like its making each array item into a line item but not populating...

Comment: @JeffreyRiggs can you post the result when you print your array in the consol?

Comment: Sure....
trying to format.. 

    DisableNotificationCenter
    Key not Found
AutoConfiURL
   HibernateEnabled
0
HideSCAHealth
1
NoDriveTypeAutoRun
TurnOffSidebar
Key not Found
EnableBaloonTips
Key not Found
UseDomainNameDevolution
1
DomainNameDevolutionlevel
2
*.one.ads
2
*
1
SearchOrderConfig
1
NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers
DisabledComponents
32
fAllowToGetHelp
1
fDenyTSConnections
EnableLUA
0
dontdisplaylastusername
0
LanmanServer
Auto
MPSSVC
Disabled
WinDefend
Manual
WSCSVC
Auto
TRKWKS
Auto
NAPAGENT
Manual
WUAUSERV
Auto
LCSAdmin
Guest
True

Comment: so i have no clue how to format to show it but it is listed one item per row.

Comment: while all over the web i found a page that said hash Table and it actually formats 2 wide how I want it.. due to the = sign.
$RegAll = @{$RegKeys[0] = $RegValues[0]} so i will try and pull in rest and then try to get this in using your outplut to see if it works

Comment: so to make it clear for me. You have one array. Each item in this array is a single string not a ps object, right? And your final result should be a table with one row which contains one item on each line. is this correct?

Comment: close. Yes I took a few arrays that were statically set and a few that were pulled items all into a final single array. No ps object at all... My final result I want is the item then result... an example is DisableNotificationCenter in column 1 row 1 and the read registry key in column 2 of row 1... then the next item onto the next row and so on

Comment: Then its much better to work with ps object. like this;
    $obj = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name key -Value "DisableNotificationCenter "
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name value -Value "here value"

Then put his objects in an arry, after this you can use my script to make an html file

Comment: so I apologize for not getting back to this sooner. All of these wannacry virus and other things have had me doing other things and my just txt file has been keeping the boss happy. I just figured out what your talking about and think I am getting there!!! HAH... will post back in a bit/while... thx

Comment: !!! WORKS LIKE A CHARM!!!!
So how do I add another table? just repeat the code and change where needed? the entire block for table?

Comment: in addition.... I just noticed that while I can read in individual items, this line which piped out to txt file shows many more, this way only puts one entry into the table
$LocalUsrs = net localgroup users | where {$_ -AND $_ -notmatch "command completed successfully"} | select -skip 4
    If (!$LocalUsrs) {$LocalUsrs = "Group is Blank"}